# How to turn off spellcheck for every control in the whole website?

Tags: html, css, attributes, spell-checking

Right now, I turn off the spellcheck for HTML controls in the website with `spellcheck="false"`. Instead of setting the attribute one at a time for every control, how can I make it work for all controls in the entire website?

An example of a control where the spell check error is shown:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck says it is a global attribute ("Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can be used on all elements, though they may have no effect on some elements.") - so, set it on a common ancestor of these elements ...? Like `body` for example.

Comment: You can post your comment as the answer. The ```spellcheck``` attribute can be set on the ```body``` tag which will disable the spellcheck on all controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck:

> The spellcheck global attribute is an enumerated attribute that defines whether the element may be checked for spelling errors.

As a global attribute, it can be set on any element. Although not *all* global attributes have an effect on *all* elements, setting `spellcheck="false"` for any element, appears to disable it for all descendants as well.

So you can put it on `body` here, and should have it off for all your content (unless explicitly specified otherwise further down the DOM tree.)